# How do I get the argument of the formal method parameter type?

Tags: java, reflection, guava, type-erasure

I have methods with a single parameter of type `Event<Something>` and need to extract the `Something` or its raw type. It may look like

```
 void method1(Event<MyEnum1> event) {}
 <E extends Enum<E>> method2(Event<E> event) {}
 <K, V> method3(Event<Map<K, V>> event) {}
```

and I'd like a function mapping

```
method1 -> MyEnum.class
method2 -> Enum.class
method3 -> Map.class
```

For `method1`, it's easy using `(ParameterizedType) method.getGenericParameterTypes()`. For `method2`, I can use Guava

```
TypeToken.of(method.getDeclaringClass())
    .method(method)
    .getTypeParameters()[0]
    .getBounds()
```

to obtain a `Type` and

```
TypeToken.of(method.getDeclaringClass())
    .method(method)
    .getParameters()
    .get(0)
```

to obtain the `Parameter`. I guess, I need to resolve the `Parameter` using the `Type`, but I'm stuck here.

I don't care much about `method3`, though it'd be good to know a general way. I don't care about the type of actual parameters (I'm aware of the erasure).

Comment: It may be interesting for someone to know why I failed. As the accepted answer shows, it's actually simple. My problem was that I've found out that `typeArgument` is  `TypeVariableImpl`, opened it in Eclipse and saw that it's private and does not implement any interface (which is impossible as it's a `Type`, but I missed it). The relevant class was `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl` (missing from sources.jar) and not the one I was looking at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `TypeToken` for this. `java.lang.reflect` provides everything you need.

You'll need to consider multiple cases. I'm going to assume the first parameter of any method provided is always of type `Event` (or really a parameterized type).

You'll need to handle the 5 subtypes of [`Type`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html). From your examples, you'll need to check whether the type argument is a concrete type (`MyEnum`), a type variable (`E` bounded by `Enum`), or a parameterized type (`Map<K,V>`).

Additionally, there is `WildcardType` which you can handle like the type variable and extract bounds.  Finally, you have to deal with generic array types with `GenericArrayType` (`Event<T[]>` or `Event<List<String>[]>`). I've left these out but it's just reapplying the same rules for the other types.

I assume, for the type variable case, the bound might be some other type variable, so we need to recur until we find the concrete bound.

```
// get raw type argument of first parameter
public static Class<?> getRawTypeArgument(Method method) {
    Parameter parameter = method.getParameters()[0];
    Type type = parameter.getParameterizedType();
    /// assume it's parameterized
    ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type;
    // assume there's one type argument
    Type typeArgument = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    if (typeArgument instanceof TypeVariable<?>) {
        TypeVariable<?> typeVariableArgument = (TypeVariable<?>) typeArgument;
        return recursivelyExtractBound(typeVariableArgument);
    } else if (typeArgument instanceof Class<?>) {
        return (Class<?>) typeArgument;
    } else if (typeArgument instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        ParameterizedType parameterizedTypeArgument = (ParameterizedType) typeArgument;
        return (Class<?>) parameterizedTypeArgument.getRawType();
    } 
    throw new AssertionError("Consider wildcard and generic type");
}

private static Class<?> recursivelyExtractBound(TypeVariable<?> typeVariable) {
    // assume first
    Type bound = typeVariable.getBounds()[0];
    if (bound instanceof Class<?>) {
        return (Class<?>) bound;
    } else if (bound instanceof TypeVariable<?>) {
        TypeVariable<?> nested = (TypeVariable<?>) bound;
        return recursivelyExtractBound(nested);
    } else if (bound instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        ParameterizedType parameterizedTypeArgument = (ParameterizedType) bound;
        return (Class<?>) parameterizedTypeArgument.getRawType();
    }
    throw new AssertionError("Are there others?");
}
```

With a small driver program

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz = Example.class;
    for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (!method.getName().startsWith("method")) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println("Method '" + method + "' -> " + getRawTypeArgument(method));
    }
}
```

the above prints out

```
Method 'java.lang.Object com.example.Example.method3(com.example.root.Event)' -> interface java.util.Map
Method 'java.lang.Object com.example.Example.method2(com.example.root.Event)' -> class java.lang.Enum
Method 'void com.example.Example.method1(com.example.Event)' -> class com.example.MyEnum1
```

Comment: This is really great! However I'd just change the `IllegalStateException` to `AssertionError`. Because it's you as the programmer who asserts there are no other coverable cases. Also, the [`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) mostly refers to the state of the object being called, and here the methods being called are static. Static and state don't usually go well together ;)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yeah.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I'm not sure about this change. I'd prefer an `AssertionRuntimeException` if it existed. An `AssertionError` might slip throw catches and cause problems... or maybe not; the Guava guys use it, too.

Comment: @maaartinus the programmer not only stated something, but strongly did so. And it turned out to be false. i wouldn't call that an exceptional case, but an error! Even Josh Bloch uses it in such scenarios (Effective Java, 2nd ed. items 4, 7 and several others including 20 where it's very similar to this answer's scenario).